# invalid value encountered in double_scalars def f(t, x): return np.power(x, 2) - x

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have been doing a lot of graphing of slope fields and ODE solutions recently, and I decided to try my hand at making a little function that automatically graphs solutions with a vector field overlay.

This function takes a set of initial conditions and plots that many solutions. It works pretty well, but for some initial values I get the error in the title:

```
invalid value encountered in double_scalars
  def f(t, x): return np.power(x, 2) - x
```

Here is the code for the function:

```
def grapher(fn, t_0, t_n, dt, y_0):
"""
Takes a first order ODE and solves it for initial conditions
provided by y_0

:param fn: y' = f(t,y) 
:param t_0: start time
:param t_n: end time
:param dt:  step size
:param y_0: iterable containing initial conditions
:return: 
"""
    t = np.arange(t_0, t_n, dt)
    y_min = .0
    y_max = .0

    for iv in np.asarray(y_0):
        soln = rk4(dt, t, fn, iv)
        plt.plot(t, soln, '-r')
        if y_min > np.min(soln):
            y_min = np.min(soln)
        if y_max < np.max(soln):
            y_max = np.max(soln)

    x = np.linspace(t_0, t_n + dt, 11)
    y = np.linspace(y_min, y_max, 11)

    X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)

    theta = np.arctan(f(X, Y))

    U = np.cos(theta)
    V = np.sin(theta)

    plt.quiver(X, Y, U, V, angles='xy')
    plt.xlim((t_0, t_n - dt))
    plt.ylim((y_min - .1*y_min, y_max + .1*y_max))
    plt.show()
```

And here is the application that fails:

```
def f(t, x): return x**2 - x

grapher(f,0,4,0.1, (-0.9, 0.9, 1.1))
```

It produces this graph, which is missing the solution associated with the initial condition 1.1:

[image]

However, if I choose a value less than or equal to 1, I get the correct graph:
[image]

I don't see an opportunity for divide by zero here, so I'm a bit confused. Also, the qualitative characteristics of the ODE are not fully on display unless I can choose an initial condition higher than 1.

I'd like to also note, that when I did not have a function to automate this process, the defined function f(x) = x^2 - x gave me no troubles at all. Any clue on why this might be?

If it helps, here is the rk4 algorithm I wrote in a different module:

```
def rk4(dt, t, field, y_0):
    """
    :param dt: float - the timestep
    :param t: array - the time mesh
    :param field: method - the vector field y' = f(t, y)
    :param y_0: array - contains initial conditions
    :return: ndarray - solution
    """

    # Initialize solution matrix. Each row is the solution to the system
    # for a given time step. Each column is the full solution for a single
    # equation.
    y = np.asarray(len(t) * [y_0])

    for i in np.arange(len(t) - 1):
        k1 = dt * field(t[i], y[i])
        k2 = dt * field(t[i] + 0.5 * dt, y[i] + 0.5 * k1)
        k3 = dt * field(t[i] + 0.5 * dt, y[i] + 0.5 * k2)
        k4 = dt * field(t[i] + dt, y[i] + k3)
        y[i + 1] = y[i] + (k1 + 2 * k2 + 2 * k3 + k4) / 6

    return y
```

Comment: `rk4` is not defined

Comment: @norok2 Added, at the bottom.

Comment: It is always a good idea to provide [enough code](/help/mcve) to allow others to reproduce your issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that there is no error in the code, just the solution gets too large.

If you called `grapher` with

```
grapher(f, 0, 4, 0.1, (-0.9, 0.9, 1.01))
```

you would get:

[image]

---

With:

```
grapher(f, 0, 4, 0.1, (-0.9, 0.9, 1.02))
```

[image]

and when `y_0` gets to be `1.1` the value for `soln` are not reported because `np.pow()`, upon detecting overflow, is just returning `nan` which then `matplotlib` does not know how to plot.

---

If you changed

```
def f(t, x):
    return x**2 - x
```

to:

```
def f(t, x):
    return x * (x - 1)
```

you would get a (ugly, but "correct") plot also of the solution for `y_0 == 1.1`, because instead of overflowing defaulting to `nan` you are now getting `inf`s as maximum values, which of course `matplotlib` does not know how to handle in the process of generating the axes:

[image]

Comment: Excellent, maybe later I can develop this tool to handle situations like that in some way.